# Deserialization and Exporting of Nested JSON API Data to CSV

Tags: c#, json, csv, serialization, json.net

I have requirement to take some data from an API from nested JSON and export it to CSV. I can't find the right syntax for taking that data to export it to CSV without creating multiple classes (there are hundreds of properties, and new ones can be added dynamically).

The JSON response structure from the API is below:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "Bus",
            "attributes": {
                "property-two": "2020-12-10",
                "property-three": "D",
                "property-four": null,
                "property-five": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "Car",
            "attributes": {
                "property-two": "2020-12-10",
                "property-three": "D",
                "property-four": null,
                "property-five": 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We only need to export the "attributes" node from each dataset to CSV, but cannot seem to flatten the data or extract just those nodes.

The following code gets a list of `JToken` objects, but I'm not sure how this can be exported to CSV without re-serializing and de-serializing again. The datatype is dynamic since columns can be added and removed from it.

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(apiResponseString);
var items = jsonObject["data"].Children()["attributes"].ToList();
//TODO: Export to CSV, DataTable etc
```

Is it possible to deserialize the data from the attributes nodes only, and how would that be done (whether on the initial `JObject.Parse` or serializing the  `JToken` list again)? I'm not tied to `JObject`, so can use Newtonsoft or other as well.

Comment: Install  **ChoETL.JSON** package from NuGet with the help of that you can easily convert json to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects), you can convert your JSON data to CSV as shown below.

First define a couple of short extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string ToCsv(this IEnumerable<JObject> items, bool includeHeaders = true)
    {
        if (!items.Any()) return string.Empty;
        var rows = new List<string>();
        if (includeHeaders)
        {
            rows.Add(items.First().Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToCsv());
        }
        rows.AddRange(items.Select(jo => 
            jo.Properties().Select(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Null ? null : p.Value).ToCsv()
        ));
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows);
    }

    public static string ToCsv(this IEnumerable<object> values)
    {
        const string quote = "\"";
        const string doubleQuote = "\"\"";
        return string.Join(",", values.Select(v => 
            v != null ? string.Concat(quote, v.ToString().Replace(quote, doubleQuote), quote) : string.Empty
        ));
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var csv = obj.SelectTokens("..attributes").Cast<JObject>().ToCsv();
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NF2G2l

Comment: Thanks Brian, I've added those methods to our base JsonHelper class now as they will be very useful. 
I ended up parsing to a datatable so that the data could be transformed and worked with as well as directly exported, though I've used your tip on the SelectTokens (i.e. i didn't need to do the SelectToken("data") first. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an extension method in my Json Helper class to convert the JToken enumerable to a datatable. This meets the original requirements to export to CSV simply (we use Aspose Cells that has a method for DatatTable to CSV), but also allows us to work with the datatable as an object without defining the columns. The end result looks like this:

**Worker Class**:

```
var stringResponse = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(stringResponse);
var dataRows = jsonObject.SelectTokens("$..attributes").ToList();
var outputData = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

dataRows.AddToDataTable(outputData, pageNumber);

//TODO: Do something with outputData (to file, to object, to DB etc)
```

**JsonHelper Class new extension method**

```
public static void AddToDataTable(this List<JToken> jTokens, DataTable dt, int pageNumber)
{
    foreach (var token in jTokens)
    {
        JObject item;
        JToken jtoken;
        if (pageNumber == 1 && dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            item = (JObject)token;
            jtoken = item.First;

            while (jtoken != null)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(((JProperty)jtoken).Name));
                jtoken = jtoken.Next;
            }
        }

        item = (JObject)token;
        jtoken = item.First;

        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        while (jtoken != null)
        {
            dr[((JProperty)jtoken).Name] = ((JProperty)jtoken).Value.ToString();
            jtoken = jtoken.Next;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```