# How can I access values at different levels of nested JObjects in a JArray to export them to a CSV file?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, export-to-csv, jira-rest-api

I'm new to C#, REST API's and JSON stuff so please bear with me. I've searched hundreds of pages and am trying to figure out how this all works. For context, I'm pulling issues from JIRA REST API using a search like `http://mylink.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3DBULK` and getting a list of issues. The JSON my program is pulling in is structured like below (this has been simplified from the actual JSON):

EDIT (04/04/2021): Updated JSON below with new use case.

```json
[
   {
     "key": "FAKE-5402",
     "fields": {
        "summary": "I need access to blah",
        "customfield_18302": [{
            "self": "fake.url.com",
            "value": "I need this"
        },  {
            "self": "fake.url2.com",
            "value": "I need this also"
        }]
     }
   },
   {
     "key": "FAKE-5450",
     "fields": {
        "summary": "Example number 2",
        "customfield_18302": [{
            "self": "fake.url3.com",
            "value": "I need this"
        },  {
            "self": "fake.url4.com",
            "value": "I need this also"
        }]
     }
   }
]
```

I'm currently working on a method that takes this JSON data, finds the keys the user is searching for and prints it out in CSV format to later be written to a file. Here is my `formatAsCSV()` function:

```cs
public void formatAsCSV()
{
    try
    {
        var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(this.jsonData);
        String issues = dynObj["issues"].ToString();

        JArray issuesArray = JArray.Parse(issues);

        List<String> columnNames = new List<String>()
        {"key", "summary"};

        String headerRow = "";
        foreach (String columnName in columnNames)
        {
            headerRow += columnName + ", ";
        }
        headerRow = headerRow.TrimEnd(' ');
        headerRow = headerRow.TrimEnd(',');
        headerRow += "\n";

        String dataRows = "";
        foreach (var record in issuesArray)
        {
            String thisRecord = "";
            foreach (String columnName in columnNames)
            {
                thisRecord += record[columnNames] + ", ";
            }

            thisRecord = thisRecord.TrimEnd(' ');
            thisRecord = thisRecord.TrimEnd(',');
            thisRecord += "\n";
            dataRows += thisRecord;
        }

        this.csvData = headerRow + dataRows;

        Console.WriteLine("\ncsvData: ");
        Console.WriteLine(this.csvData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in formatAsCSV: " + ex);
        this.errorsOccurred = true;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having with the above code (and I've tried for days to figure this out...) is that it pulls in all of the issues as separate objects. So when the code loops through, I am able to get the "key", "expand", "id", "self" because they aren't nested. The same code will not grab stuff that's nested under "fields" when I need things like the "summary" and "issuetype" -> "name". I have no idea where to start with getting this information.

Here is the output I would get from something like this (notice the summary is missing after the first comma):

```
csvData:
key, summary
BULK-62, 
BULK-47,
```

If anyone has any ideas, let me know because I'm running out of things to try. Most issues on here start issues as a JObject but I keep getting errors and "issues" is the main thing I pull which is an array, not an object, so not sure how to handle this. I know it can work SOMEHOW since JIRA allows CSV pulls through a manual process. I'm hoping there's a way to keep the process I have (it's from following a YT tutorial) so I don't have to rewrite everything I've already done but I understand if it comes down to that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar question here: [Deserialization and Exporting of Nested JSON API Data to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65345502/10263)

Comment: @dbc Thanks for letting me know, I went ahead and made some changes. My work won't allow pasting to this site so I super simplified the JSON to still be enough to figure out the issue. Brian, I haven't seen that one yet so I'll give that a go and see if I can get it to work in the meantime. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65345502/10263) I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348125/10263) where the asker wanted to extract all properties from a nested [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and have those values become the CSV columns.  In your case you want to pick and choose properties at different levels from the object and its children.

The key to solving this effectively is using the [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method to your advantage.  This method accepts a [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression, which lets you query a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to find one of its descendants.  In its simplest form, this is just a dot-delimited string, such as `fields.summary`.

Borrowing a bit from the other question, I would make two helper methods.  The first method would accept a list of `JObjects` representing row items along with a `Dictionary<string, string>` which maps the column names to the corresponding paths that will be used to retrieve the values from each item.  The second method would accept a list of values and turn that into a CSV row.

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string ToCsv(this IEnumerable<JObject> items, Dictionary<string, string> columnPathMappings)
    {
        if (items == null || columnPathMappings == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var rows = new List<string>();
        rows.Add(columnPathMappings.Keys.ToCsv());
        foreach (JObject item in items)
        {
            rows.Add(columnPathMappings.Values.Select(path => item.SelectToken(path)).ToCsv());
        }
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows);
    }

    public static string ToCsv(this IEnumerable<object> values)
    {
        const string quote = "\"";
        const string doubleQuote = "\"\"";
        return string.Join(",", values.Select(v => 
            v != null ? string.Concat(quote, v.ToString().Replace(quote, doubleQuote), quote) : string.Empty
        ));
    }
}
```

Armed with these methods, all you would need to do to create the CSV string is set up your mappings, then parse the JSON, extract the items array from it and call the helper to do the rest:

```
var columnPathMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "key", "key" },
    { "summary", "fields.summary" }
};

string csv = JArray.Parse(json).Cast<JObject>().ToCsv(columnPathMappings);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zzBpbT

---

If your JSON has an inner array, then that implies that there will be multiple values possible for a particular column in a single row.  Given that CSV is a flat structure, multiple values need to be joined together into a newline-delimited string before being inserted into the CSV.  You can modify the above code to do that like this:

1. In the first method change `SelectToken` to `SelectTokens`.  This will allow it to extract multiple values for a single path instead of just one.
2. In the second method, check for and handle the possibility that the object in `IEnumerable<object> values` is itself an `IEnumerable<Jtoken>`.  In that case, join the JTokens together into a newline-delimited string and then handle that string as before.

The modified code would look like this:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string ToCsv(this IEnumerable<JObject> items, Dictionary<string, string> columnPathMappings)
    {
        if (items == null || columnPathMappings == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var rows = new List<string>();
        rows.Add(columnPathMappings.Keys.ToCsv());
        foreach (JObject item in items)
        {
            rows.Add(columnPathMappings.Values.Select(path => item.SelectTokens(path)).ToCsv());
        }
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows);
    }

    public static string ToCsv(this IEnumerable<object> values)
    {
        const string quote = "\"";
        const string doubleQuote = "\"\"";
        return string.Join(",", values.Select(v => 
        {
            if (v != null)
            {
                if (v is IEnumerable<JToken> e)
                {
                    v = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Select(t => t.ToString()));  
                }
                return string.Concat(quote, v.ToString().Replace(quote, doubleQuote), quote);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }));
    }
}
```

The last step is that you need to specify a path which will get the child values in the array.  To do that, you can use a wildcard `*` in the path for the array index.  So your mappings would look like this:

```
var columnPathMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "key", "key" },
    { "summary", "fields.summary" },
    { "customfield_18302", "fields.customfield_18302[*].value" },
};
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IfB8sw

Comment: This is honestly incredible, not only is this exactly what I was looking for, it'll make updating to add more fields MUCH easier for me. Thank you. I do have an issue with rows.Add(columnPathMappings.Values.Select(path => item.SelectToken(path).ToCsv())); as I get an error saying "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'" using this code in VS2019 so not sure what's going on, despite seeing that it works perfectly in the demo you linked. Either way, marking this as the answer. Thanks for everything, really.

Comment: You've got your parentheses wrong.  Be sure to copy the whole line exactly as I have it.

Comment: That's embarrassing. Works like a charm. You've saved me much more headaches!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Hello, this is working very well so far but I've run into an issue here. I've tried to fix it for a couple of weeks to no avail. You wouldn't really have known since the JSON wasn't provided fully in my original example (I just found out about these nested array fields...) but the code isn't pulling in any information to the Excel sheet when the field it's pulling has an array inside of it. It's just blank, is it possible to do foreach (JObject... and then if there's an array, it'll go down further? I'm guessing it can't access the stuff inside of the array since I'm only calling JObject.

Comment: Forgot to add that I updated my JSON in my original post to better explain what I'm seeing and having issues pulling.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this new requirement.

Comment: Thank you! You're an absolute wizard. This stuff is not easy to learn I'm finding out.

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to access is nested deeper in the Json Object.
Please pay attention to the Json structure. The field "summary" is nested in the object "fields" so to access it you need to first access the fields object.

This means, that you'll have to rethink your approach with the column names list.